# How to find out how much memory is used by my native (ndk) app?

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, heap-memory, android-memory

I want in my app (Delphi app, build with NDK) to get a snapshot of some key elements:

- how much memory does the system have
- how much memory is available (for my app)
- how much memory my app (native, using NDK) use
- If it's different kind of memory than previous, how much memory is used by texture in openGL

I read so many articles, answers about this, all with different answers. some use activity manager, another runtime, other debug, etc. Example, when I do using `Runtime`:

```
Runtime.getRuntime.totalMemory => 26 Mb
Runtime.getRuntime.freeMemory => 7 Mb
Runtime.getRuntime.maxMemory => 134 Mb
```

I sincerely doubt that my app uses only 26 MB as it uses many textures. Anyway when I do with `MemoryInfo (ActivityManager.getMemoryInfo)` I have

```
MemoryInfo.totalMem => 1970 Mb
MemoryInfo.availMem=> 877 Mb
```

that is quite completely different than what I have with Runtime

Comment: Runtime is only going to get the Java memory, because that's all the Java runtime knows about.  I suggest you use the memory profiler to find total memory use.

Comment: @GabeSechan: I need to take the snapshot from inside my app so i can't use a memory profiler

Comment: Then you're best off skipping android and dropping down to linux level and reading the /proc/self filesystem

Comment: Actually, ActivityMnager.getProcessMemoryInfo might give you what you want

Comment: @GabeSechan ok with getProcessMemoryInfo , but there is so many think in it (nativePss, nativeSharedDirty, dalvikPrivateDirty, etc.) ... how to use those numbers?

Comment: Native is c++, dalvik is java. For the rest, those are coming memory terms. Memory is complicated, if you were expecting just a used and available you wouldn't really get any serious use out of that.

Comment: @GabeSechan yes I agree, this why this stackoverflow question ;) to have a good view of how to do correctly thing as it's a complicated task

Comment: You actually may prefer to look at the getMemoryStats function off of the MemoryInfo that returns.  Its v23+, but it provides the native and Java heap sizes, code size, stack size, graphics memory size, swap, pss, etc.  It might provide the most easily understood view of things.

Comment: @GabeSechan, unfortunately, I need to support at least android 4 (kitkat)